# compute this integration

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}x^3+a}}{(1-x)\sqrt{x}\sqrt{-\frac{4}{3}x^3+x^2-a}}dx$$

where $a\in(0,\frac{1}{12})$ is a constant. In this case, $-\frac{4}{3}x^3+x^2-a=0$ has exactly two roots in $(0,1)$. $x_1,x_2$ are the two roots in $(0,1)$.

Thank you.

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: someone asked me this. he need to compute this in his paper about Riemannia Geometry.

Comment: if this integration cannot be computed, proving the integration increases as $a$ increases in also helpful

Comment: It seems to me it can, but it will be rather complicated, and the result might have to be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals. If you're fine with that...

Comment: The answer is $2\pi/3$, by wolframalpha.

Comment: @Yimin where is $a$?

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your problem, apologize for that spam. it is a simple case that a=0.

Comment: @J.M. , er, any results will be fine. I would appreciate it if you post your results!